# updateOne query only modifying first matching element of array despite multiple matches

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

https://mongoplayground.net/p/zIhLOT8YXLl

document schema:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId();
  array_property: [ {_id: ObjectId(), img_array: ["string", "string"] }, { }, ... ]
}
```

query:

```
 await user.updateOne(
            {
              _id: user_id,
              array_property: { $elemMatch: { _id: { $in: arrary_of_id } } },
            },
            {
              $push: {
                "array_property.$.img_array": {
                  $each: [new_img],
                },
              },
            }
          );
```

despite multiple elements of `array_property` matching the query, the `$push` will only happen to the first matching element. The rest are not modified.

How to fix this? The query is intended to update all matching elements of `array_property`.

Comment: this will update all elements in the array. However, I just want to update the elements of the array that matches the `{ $elemMatch: { _id: { $in: arrary_of_id } } }`

Answer (score 0):

use `arrayFilters`:

```
db.collection.update({
  key: 1
},
{
  $set: {
    cheese: "farts"
  },
  $push: {
    "a.$[x].b": {
      $each: [
        4
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "x.id": {
        $in: [
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/CwH6ZActsv_https://mongoplayground.net/p/CwH6ZActsv_